# Read & change rotate value of an Element in SnapSVG

Tags: javascript, matrix, svg, transform, snap.svg

Pls Check out this incomplete fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/JayKandari/srqLLd97/).

Markup:

```
<svg id="paper" ></svg>
<div id="workingArea">
    <button onclick="calculateTransform()">Get Transform</button>
    <div class="results">
        Transform: <span class="transformResult"></span>
    </div>
    <button onclick="rotateText('add')">Rotate + 10 Degrees</button>
    <button onclick="rotateText('sub')">Rotate - 10 Degrees</button>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
console.clear();
var paper = Snap("#paper");

var t = paper.text(0, 0, "SnapSVG is Awesome !");
//Translate to 250, 250 & Scale by 2 & 45Deg Rotate
t.transform('T250,250 S2 R45');
// Enable Drag
t.drag();

var calculateTransform = function() {
    var currentTransform = t.transform().string;
    console.log('test', currentTransform)
    $('.results .transformResult').html(currentTransform)
}

var rotateText = function(op) {
    // Read Current Rotate Value here.
    var rotateVal = 0;
    // add/Subtract based on option
    if(op == 'add'){
        rotateVal += 10;
    }else if(op == 'sub') {
        rotateVal -= 10;
    }

    // Calculate newTransform here.
    var newTransform = 'T250,250 R' + rotateVal;

    // Update object's rotation here. 
    t.attr({transform: newTransform });
}
```

Problems:

- Read current transformation applied to Element.
- Rotate current Element to a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably are after in your mind is something like this...

```
var rotateVal = t.transform().localMatrix.split().rotate;
```

localMatrix gives the matrix specifically applied to that element.

globalMatrix gives the total matrix applying to that element (eg matrices from outer containers).

diffMatrix gives the difference between localMatrix and globalMatrix.

split() ( [docs here](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Matrix.split) ) breaks down that matrix into its elements. So we can find 'rotate' from here.

[example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/srqLLd97/2/)

So this is the answer I think you are after.

However, I would actually design the code the slightly different if this is just a minimal example of a more complex design.

Rather than doing something like transform().localMatrix.split().rotate, I would store your own transform components. So something like...

```
var rotate = 45;
var tx = 250;
var ty = 250;
...then in func
rotate += +10;
var newTransform = 'T'+tx+','+ty+'R'+rotate;
```

The reason for this, is that you are now controlling precisely the values, and its not really prone to errors (from the lib or misunderstanding about matrices). If you look at your matrix values you display, you will note there are subtle rounding differences, plus with complex matrix calculations, the values aren't quite what we expect and don't always split in a nice easy way that makes sense.

So if this is the main example, the first bit of code will probably suffice. If you are doing more complex transformations, I would think about controlling the values yourself and building up the transform string like the latter example.